# Removing second and subsequent occurrences of decimal point in string

Tags: r, string, stringr

I want to remove second and subsequent occurrences of decimal point in string. My attempt is below:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(string = "3.99-0.13", pattern = "\\.")
[1] "399-0.13"
sub("\\.", "", "3.99-0.13")
[1] "399-0.13"
```

However, I want the output like `3.99-013`. Any hint, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concise solution is based on look-behind:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(x, "(?<=\\..{0,10})\\.")
[1] "3.99-01322" "3.99013"
```

Here, the look-behind `(?<=\\..{0,10})` asserts that a `.` must already have occurred before the `str_remove_all` operation is carried out.

Data:

```
x <- c("3.99-0.13.2.2", "3.990.13")
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `sub` and `gsub` with simple regex patterns that works on a variety of possible inputs.

Extract the first part, then remove all dots from the second part, finally paste the two together.

##### Data

```
stri <- c("3.99-0.13", "393.99.0.13.0.0", ".832.723.723", "3.Ud.2349_3.", 
"D.235.2")

stri
[1] "3.99-0.13"       "393.99.0.13.0.0" ".832.723.723"    "3.Ud.2349_3."   
[5] "D.235.2"
```

apply

```
paste0(sub("\\..*", ".", stri), gsub("\\.", "", sub(".*?\\.", "", stri)))
[1] "3.99-013"    "393.9901300" ".832723723"  "3.Ud2349_3"  "D.2352"
```

Comment: (+1). Thanks @AndreWildberg for very useful answer. I guess this will remove the last decimal. Wondering how to delete all decimals after the first.

Comment: You assume there must be a hyphen between the first and second decimals, right?

Comment: Not working correctly for `str_replace("3.990.13", "(-.*)(\\.)", "\\1")`.

Answer (score 1):

We could locate all occurrences of `.`'s, exclude the first, and remove the rest:

```r
library(stringi)

x <- c("3.99-0.13.2.2", "3.990.13")

stri_sub_replace_all(x,
                     lapply(stri_locate_all_regex(x, '\\.'), \(x) x[-1,, drop = FALSE]),
                     replacement = "")
```

Output:

```r
"3.99-01322" "3.99013"
```

Note: `stringr`'s `str_sub` doesn't seem to have a `replace_all` option, so we'll need `stringi` for this (that said, `stringr::str_locate_all` could be used instead of `stri_locate_all_regex` if you prefer).

**Update:** Now works with `<= 2` occurrences.

Comment: Not working correctly for `x2 <- "3.990.13"
stri_sub_replace_all(
    x2
  , stri_locate_all_regex(x2, '\\.')[[1]][-1,]
  , replacement = ""
  )`

Comment: See update. The subsetting turned the locations into a named vector when there is only one occurrence of `.` left after removing the first.